# uint64_t in C acting as a uint32_t

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a number that is 16 digits long 0x1122334455667788 and bit shift it to account for little endian numbering.

Using the following example code to load the number in from memory cells

```
void endianCompute(memory_t memory, uint64_t start, uint64_t *save, int size){
    *save = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i  < size; i++){
        *save += memory[start + i] << (i)*8;
        printf("add 0x%x\n", memory[start + i] << (i)*8);
        printf("save 0x%x\n", *save);
    }
}
```

The output produces :

```
save 0x88
add 0x7700
save 0x7788
add 0x660000
save 0x667788
add 0x55000000
save 0x55667788
add 0x44
save 0x556677cc
add 0x3300
save 0x5566aacc
add 0x220000
save 0x5588aacc
add 0x11000000
save 0x6688aacc
```

This makes sense to me up until the add 0x44, why does the bit shift not continue to push the numbers to the left? Why am I not able to make a number past 8 digits?

Comment: what is `memory_t`? Also, your `save` line prints out before your `add` line?

Comment: In order to print `uint64_t` you need a different format specifier, like `%llx`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on compiler warnings, probably with `-Wall`, and the problem is revealed.

```
cc -Wall -g test.c   -o test
test.c:10:27: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    printf("save 0x%x\n", *save);
                   ~~     ^~~~~
                   %llx
```

You need to use `%llx` to print a 64 bit integer (long long int).

Comment: It would be more portable to use the `PRIx64` macro from `stdint.h` to supply the field code: `printf("save 0x" PRIx64 "\n", *save);`.  That accounts for implementation variation with respect to which type corresponds to `uint64_t`.